# Return result of XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to return the result of an XMLHTTPRequest:

```
<a href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">Click me for Google CDN jQuery!</a> 

<script>
    const url = {
        httpRequest: function(callback) {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.addEventListener("load", callback);
            xhr.open("GET", document.querySelector("a").href); // Using querySelector to simulate how my real program works - I don't want to hardcode anything mainly because this should be dynamic.
            xhr.send("");
        },
        compileData: function(data) {
            var response = data.target.responseText.substring(4, 17) 
            // I can't figure out how to take this response and 'return' it.
        },
        getContent: function() {
            url.httpRequest(url.compileData)
        }
    }

     var content = url.getContent() // I want 'content' to be equal to "jQuery v3.3.1"
</script>
```

But, I can't figure out how to 'return' the response.

***Yes***, I know that there are other questions out there like this one, namely: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) But, I'm new to JavaScript and have no idea how to integrate what they're saying there into my case.

Comment: Sorry but I must be honest with you. You don't an SO answer, you need a javascript basic course.

Comment: Look at promises, or you could pass a callback to the compiledata callback to retrieve into your function where you need it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), [Promises](http://2ality.com/2014/09/es6-promises-foundations.html) and [more Promises](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises)! And you should return one from your function.

```
function httpRequest() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onload = (response) => {
            resolve(response); // You should check the response and maybe preprocess it 
                               //   so that not everything is passed further
        }
        xhr.open("GET", document.querySelector("a").href);
        xhr.send("");
    });
}
```

and then you may use `then` and `catch`

```
httpRequest().then((data) => {
    // Yay! Got response from the server!
}).catch((error) => {
    // Yay! More errors!
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A few options for applying the guidance given in "[How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)"

1. If you'd like to continue using callbacks, then it's a matter of adding another. The result you'll want is to allow your entry point to accept its own:

   ```
   url.getContent(function (content) {
     // proceed with `content` here
   });
   ```

   So, `getContent` needs to expect the argument:

   ```
   getContent: function(callback) {
     // ...
   }
   ```

   But, it also needs to call the `callback`, which it can do with yet another intermediate function, so it can combine `callback` with `compileData`:

   ```
   getContent: function(callback) {
     url.httpRequest(function (data) {
       callback(url.compileData(data));
     });
   }
   ```
2. You can also use Promises throughout the `url` object.

   Starting with `httpRequest`, you can utilize [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and [its shortcuts](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/shorthand-methods/) returning a customized promise object – a [`jqXHR`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR):

   ```
   httpRequest: function () {
     return Promise.resolve(
       jQuery.get(document.querySelector("a").href)
     );
   }
   ```

   In this, [`Promise.resolve()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve) can be used to convert the customized promise into a standard `Promise`.

   Then, `getContent` can be modified to interact with the promise, modifying the response with `compileData`:

   ```
   getContent: function () {
     return url.httpRequest().then(url.compileData);
   }
   ```

   And, the caller can add its own handler using the [`Promise`'s methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response):

   ```
   url.getContent().then(function (content) {
     // proceed with `content` here
   });
   ```

   > Also, a brief aside... In supporting browsers, you can use [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) in place of `jQuery.ajax()`, which already returns a standard `Promise`, but will first give you a [`Response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) object rather than the raw `data`.
   >
   > ```
   > httpRequest: function () {
   >   return fetch(document.querySelector("a").href)
   >     .then(response => response.text())
   > }
   > ```

Answer (score 0):

There are three different ways according to 3 JS standards i.e es5,es6 and es7 but here you have used xhr therefore it is an old standard.

Hence, you should use xhr.onload method of xhr object over here to return the response. Simply do:

`xhr.onload = callback;`
insert this code between xhr.open and xhr.send.